# Problema superposición HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema de superposición con HTML y CSS básicos. El problema es que tengo una sección definida, y después de esta declaro div, pero se superpone a la sección (en las imágenes se ve más claramente). Os dejo el código junto a imágenes descriptivas.

```css
/** LISTA PRECIOS **/
ul.lista-precios > li { /* Solo el primer li */
  padding: 1rem;
}
@media(min-width:768px){
  ul.lista-precios{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
div.tabla-precio {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
div.tabla-precio:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border: 1px solid #fe4918;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #666;
}
div.tabla-precio ul li {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #868686;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
}
div.tabla-precio ul li i {
  color: green;
}
div.tabla-precio h3 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.tabla-precio p.numero {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 5em;
}

/** MAPA **/
div.mapa {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="precios seccion">
  <h2>Precios</h2>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <ul class="lista-precios clearfix">
      <li>
        <div class="tabla-precio">
          <h3>Pase por día</h3>
          <p class="numero">$30</p>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Bocadillos gratis</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todas las conferencias</li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todos los talleres</li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" class="button hollow">Comprar</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul> <!-- .lista-precios -->
  </div> <!-- .contenedor -->
</section>

<div id="mapa" class="mapa">

</div>
```

Lo que se ve es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si inspecciono me doy cuenta de que la sección termina en este punto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Que es justo donde empieza mi div.
¿Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: eso pasa porque usas float, al usarlo los elementos flotando salen del flujo y se superponen a los otros. Lo que podrias hacer es usar flexbox en vez de floats, es mucho mejor.

Comment: prueba a cambiar float: left; por display: flex; y obtendras el mismo resultado pero con la franja verde al pie. Hay un buen tutorial de flexbox en el canal de YT de Jonmircha

Comment: @HernánGarcia, podrías publicar un respuesta aportando como resolverías el problema a través de flex.

Answer (score 1):

Al usar `float`, siempre tenes que poner al ultimo del contenedor que contiene esos flotantes un div llamado `clear`, a `clear` le asignas desde el `css` `clear: both;`

**clear**
La propiedad `CSS clear` especifica si un elemento puede estar al lado de elementos flotantes que lo preceden o si debe ser movido (cleared) debajo de ellos. La propiedad clear aplica a ambos elementos flotantes y no flotantes.

**both**
Es un keyword que indica que el elemento es movido hacia abajo para limpiar tanto elementos flotantes de la izquierda como de la derecha.

entonces quedaría así tu código:

```css
/** LISTA PRECIOS **/
        ul.lista-precios > li { /* Solo el primer li */
          padding: 1rem;
        }
        @media(min-width:768px){
          ul.lista-precios{
            float: left;
            width: 33.3%;
          }
        }
        div.tabla-precio {
          border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
          background-color: #fff;
          padding: 4rem 0;
          text-align: center;
          transition: all .3s ease;
        }
        div.tabla-precio:hover{
          transform: scale(1.1);
          border: 1px solid #fe4918;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #666;
        }
        div.tabla-precio ul li {
          font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.4rem;
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          color: #868686;
          line-height: 2.6rem;
        }
        div.tabla-precio ul li i {
          color: green;
        }
        div.tabla-precio h3 {
          font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.6rem;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        div.tabla-precio p.numero {
          color: #000;
          margin-top: 1.5rem;
          font-size: 5em;
        }

        /** MAPA **/
        div.mapa {
          height: 10rem;
          background-color: green;
        }
        .clear {
          clear: both;
        }
```

```html
<section class="precios seccion">
        <h2>Precios</h2>
        <div class="contenedor">
          <ul class="lista-precios clearfix">
            <li>
              <div class="tabla-precio">
                <h3>Pase por día</h3>
                <p class="numero">$30</p>
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Bocadillos gratis</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todas las conferencias</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todos los talleres</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="button hollow">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul> <!-- .lista-precios -->
        </div> <!-- .contenedor -->
      </section>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="mapa" class="mapa">
      
      </div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Hola, gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas. Por lo que veo el problema esta en usar float en vez de los display que nos da CSS. Hare los cambios y comentare por aqui los resultados, pero entonces me surge una pregunta: ¿es mejor usar flexbox/grid antes que float? En caso de que dependa de la situación, en qué situaciones es idóneo cada uno. Gracias.

Comment: En mi caso me resulta mas fácil y rápido usar `Flexbox`, ya que puedo lograr mas rápido lo que quiero maquetar sin estar asignándole valores extras como `padding`, `margin`, etc, pero tampoco es malo usar `float`, nada mas que es la manera antigua que se usaba `float` al maquetar, por eso llego la salvación de `flexbox` que logras resultados mas óptimos y mas rápido y con poco línea de códigos!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que CSS son estilos en cascada, por lo que los estilos de algunos elementos pueden afectar a otros, generalmente al usar float recomiendo usar clear:boat; en el div padre, esto para evitar que los elementos flotantes afecten a otros, por ejemplo:

```css
/** LISTA PRECIOS **/
        ul.lista-precios > li { /* Solo el primer li */
          padding: 1rem;
        }
        @media(min-width:768px){
          ul.lista-precios{
            float: left;
            width: 33.3%;
          }
        }
        div.tabla-precio {
          border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
          background-color: #fff;
          padding: 4rem 0;
          text-align: center;
          transition: all .3s ease;
        }
        div.tabla-precio:hover{
          transform: scale(1.1);
          border: 1px solid #fe4918;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #666;
        }
        div.tabla-precio ul li {
          font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.4rem;
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          color: #868686;
          line-height: 2.6rem;
        }
        div.tabla-precio ul li i {
          color: green;
        }
        div.tabla-precio h3 {
          font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.6rem;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        div.tabla-precio p.numero {
          color: #000;
          margin-top: 1.5rem;
          font-size: 5em;
        }

        /** MAPA **/
        div.mapa {
          height: 10rem;
          background-color: green;
        }
        .mapa {
          clear: both;
        }
```

```html
<section class="precios seccion">
        <h2>Precios</h2>
        <div class="contenedor">
          <ul class="lista-precios clearfix">
            <li>
              <div class="tabla-precio">
                <h3>Pase por día</h3>
                <p class="numero">$30</p>
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Bocadillos gratis</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todas las conferencias</li>
                  <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Todos los talleres</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="button hollow">Comprar</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul> <!-- .lista-precios -->
        </div> <!-- .contenedor -->
      </section>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="mapa" class="mapa">
      
      </div>
```

Sin embargo hay otras formas de alinear elementos en columnar, mi recomendación es usar un div padre con la propiedad flex, dentro puedes agregar divs hijos con la propiedad inline-block, estos se alinearan sin afectar a otros elementos usando flexbox, aquí un ejemplo:

```css
.padre {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; /* Usamos flexbox en nuestro div padre */
}

.hijo {
  width: 33.33%; /* Agregamos un tamaño*/
  display: inline-block; /* Usamos inline-block en los divs hijos*/
}

.contenedor-hijo {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">

  <div class="hijo">
    <div class="contenedor-hijo">
      <h2>Titulo</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hijo">
    <div class="contenedor-hijo">
      <h2>Titulo</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="hijo">
    <div class="contenedor-hijo">
      <h2>Titulo</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Efectivamente era por el uso de float y no hacer el clear. Pasare eso a flexbox al ser más versátil. Gracias por el apoyo. Un saludo